# How to tell if JDK is available from within running JVM?

Tags: java, jvm, liferay

Note: All the similar questions are answering this from the perspective of the shell (e.g. Is `javac` available? `java -version` or `which java`). I'm looking explicitly for the *perspective of the currently running* JVM.

There are programs that require to be run from within a JDK's JRE, not "just" a JRE. I'm wondering if there's a simple way to find out what my *currently running program* is executed in.

I'm looking for a generic way to figure this out, rather than an analysis of the program in question and duplicating its use of JDK features. That's why I'd prefer not to execute an external process testing if `javac` is on the path, if possible. I'm rather looking for some code that will *run* within a JDK, but *fail* within a JRE.

It could be `Class.forName` with a class that's only available in a JDK. It could be a system property. Or anything else.

If I *have to* execute an external process with javac: So be it. But I'd prefer something simpler and generic.

**Clarification** from deep down in the comments:

From time to time I'm running into this problem with Liferay, which requires to be run from within a JDK's JRE. I was entertaining the thought to just deploy another plugin that provides a userfriendly error message if run without a JDK available. I shy away from analyzing which code is the one failing in a JRE-only environment, and I don't want to modify Liferay's code, rather add my own plugin to do the analysis and warn.

Comment: It will always be running on a JRE.

Comment: So the *only* special features of a JDK available *are* the *externally available* programs?

Comment: The JDK supplies the tools to build a Java application and has a JRE included to run applications on. A JRE installation just has the JRE and no build tools.

Comment: The JDK contains a JRE. You are always running on a JRE. As such, your question is founded upon a false premise.

Comment: execute /.../jvm/jdk/bin/java and you'll see `Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS)`

Comment: Consider the keywords: a "kit" is something that you use; an "environment" is something that you live in.  You make something in the kit and then run it in the environment.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. I've changed the question title to be more accurate. I guess my only chance then is to execute `javac` from within the JVM. I was hoping I can avoid that through any other internal feature of the JDK's JRE.

Comment: @OlafKock How do you expect invoking `javac` to help you? I could have JDK6 installed, with `javac` on my path. I could be running the application in JRE 8.

Comment: Overall this seems like an XY problem to me. **Why** do you want to know? What are you hoping to accomplish?

Comment: Since Java has become modular, the distinction between JRE and JDK is obsolete. You have to clarify *which feature* you need and then, check for the presence of that feature. If it is the compiler, you can check for the presence of the compiler API. But if you don’t use that API but require the presence of a command line `javac` tool, you have to check for precisely that.

Comment: Fair question: From time to time I'm running into this problem myself, or with other people (in Liferay, which requires to be run from within a JDK's JRE). I was entertaining the thought to just deploy another plugin that provides a userfriendly error message if run without a JDK available. I shy away from analyzing which code is the one failing, and I don't want to change the product's code, rather add my own.

Comment: @OlafKock "in Liferay, which requires to be run from within a JDK's JRE" For what?

Comment: @Michael that's precisely what I don't want to dive into the code for. I assume it might be JSP compilation within the OSGi container, but I might be wrong. It just does not run in JRE-only.

Comment: So you’re saying, the problem is that Liferay has certain requirements on the environment, but doesn’t provide a user friendly error message? Then, you should file a bug report to Liferay’s developers and that’s it.

Comment: I would actually reword the question once more... smth like: "How to tell from within a Java program whether it is running in a JDK or JRE". The word "available" seems a bit weird.

Comment: @StefanReich according to the discussion above, 1) one is always running in a JRE 2) the JDK might or might not be available externally. While it's not what I thought of initially, it's probably technically more correct to ask for availability, than for "being inside a JDK".

Comment: Indeed, the most correct term probably being “the availability of JDK features”.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`javax.tools.ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler()` will return `null` if no compiler is available, and a `JavaCompiler` if it is.

Technically it just tells you if the *compiler* is available of course, but that in most scenarios will imply the existence of the JDK.

Comment: Ah, that might be even better than my answer.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. That looks like it's also working in OpenJDKs, as they might not necessarily duplicate com.sun.*

Comment: Of course, that won’t tell you whether a command line `javac` command exists nor whether a software, naively assuming to run in a `jre` directy inside a `jdk` installation (which is not the case since Java 9), will work with the current environment.

Comment: @Holger: Good enough for a quickfix to the current pain. In the long run, your comment is right: Bring a friendlier message into the core product. But that's the long run, and I'm rather impatient.

Answer (score 4):

`Class.forName("com.sun.tools.javac.Main");`

If there is no exception, it is a JDK.

It works with current JDKs, but it's probably not part of any official spec.

Comment: Thanks - as you write in Michael's answer, and see in my comment there, I'll probably rather go with his, assuming it's working in any JDK, not just Oracle's.

Comment: @OlafKock No problem. I will cry only shortly. :-)